# SSD drive used space higher than individual folders

Tags: windows-10, ssd

This is a screenshot from WinDirStat. This is a 4TB SSD drive.

[image]

As you see it says 3 TB used for the whole drive.
If you add the 3 folders  1.1 + 1.0 + 0.772 = 2.872
I'm missing like 200 GB.

using Window 10 explorer properties on Z: gives 2.95 TB. selecting all folders with explorer gives 2.69 TB with windows explorer. Again the sizes dont match.

As you see there is no leftover in recycle bin and there are no big hidden files. I have no extra large hidden or system files on this drive. The Win 10 System Restore is also off on this drive. Is this difference of 200 GB normal?

Comment: 2.872 GB makes it sound like you are using MBR instead of GPT is that the case?  You should have a drive larger then 3 TB if you have 4 TB SSD.  Explorer Properties is limited by the permissions of the user that ran it.  It is not clear what your question is exactly.

Comment: The drive is GPT and not MBR. I think the question is clear. Properties on drive gives 2.95 TB used. When I go inside the drive and select all the root folders, properties gives only 2.69 TB. No hidden files or anything big inside recycle bin exist.

Comment: You are missing 700 GB if the drive is a 4 TB drive.

Comment: No I am not. Why are you saying I'm missing 700 GB?